# Understanding pandas.DataFrame.corrwith method for spearman rank correlation calculation column-wise and row-wise

Tags: pandas, dataframe, nan

I have two dataframes like so :

```
preds_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records ([[ 0.8224],  [ 0.7982]]) 
tgts_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records ([[0.8889], [1.0000]])
```

and want to compute spearman rank correlation values both across columns and across rows:

```
col_wise = preds_df.corrwith(tgts_df,method='spearman',axis=0).values.tolist()
row_wise = preds_df.corrwith(tgts_df,method='spearman',axis=1).values.tolist()
```

Printing those values gives:

```
print(col_wise)
[-0.9999999999999999]
print(row_wise)
[nan, nan]
```

**Question 1:** `col_wise` produced some result but how come `row_wise` produce `nan` for each row given that each row contained exactly one column and the value obtained for `col_wise` is not `nan`?

If I further extend these datasets (keep the original column but add two more columns) such that

```
preds_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records ([[0.8224,  0.5371,  0.1009],  [0.7982,  0.5890,  0.0962]])
tgts_df = pd.DataFrame.from_records ([[0.8889, 0.5556, 0.0000], [1.0000, 0.7778, 0.0000]])
```

the values obtained are:

```
col_wise = preds_df.corrwith(tgts_df,method='spearman',axis=0).values.tolist()
print(col_wise)
[-0.9999999999999999, 0.9999999999999999, nan]

row_wise = preds_df.corrwith(tgts_df,method='spearman',axis=1).values.tolist()
print(row_wise)
[1.0, 1.0]
```

**Question 2:** Why doesn't the `row_wise` contain `nan` even though one of the columns (the third one) making each row has produced `nan` in `col_wise`?

**Question 3:** In general, why are `nan` values obtained? My input dataframes all have real numbers in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1:**
Note that when you want to calculate the Spearman correlation coefficient row-wise, you get two one-element samples from both frames (`0.8224, 0.8889`) corresponding to the first element in the list of coefficients and (`0.7982,1.0000`) corresponding to the other. Now look at the [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient#Definition) for the coefficient. Because you have one observation in both samples, the denominator equals zero and that is why you get `NaN` value.

**Question 2 and 3:**
The above issue does not apply to your second example, but you have observations with the same value (`0.0`) in the last column in `tgts_df` which results in the so called tied ranks (see [more here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/7941/what-is-tied-data-in-the-context-of-a-rank-correlation-coefficient)). There are generally three situations when you are going to get `NaN` values:

**1.** You have samples with only one element in each group.

**2.** There are ties in the data (observations with the same values).

**3.** The shape of two dataframe objects is not the same.

If you have any further issues/questions, feel free to ask a question on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/).